# Is it safe to version control an API key for Google API's

Tags: android, version-control, api-key, google-developers-console

I have a open source android app. 
In order to use for example the new Awareness API I need to have an **api key** that my application will be using.

That one is generated by providing the package name and the SHA-1 of the certificate.

The place where it's stored is the `Manifest.xml` which **of course is version controlled**.

Is this safe? Since my project is opensource anybody will be able to see this key, but can he actually use it? Why?

P.S. The instruction for the above can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-a-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Version Controlling it, I would instead put it in a separate XML File, and put it in the `.gitignore`. You can reference the XML File in the String Resources file, and instead of using the hard coded API Key, use the String Resource that corresponds to the API Key, like `@string/API_KEY`. That is a much safer way to do this. This way, you are not opening your key up to public access, and the application still has the corresponding data it needs.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Went with your solution. For now it works although I would really want to know the logic behind the sha-1, and really if its ok to expose the api key

Comment: In the case of non-public source control (slight diversion from the Q), wouldn't this key still be retrievable by someone de-compiling the app? If so, it there really much point, given the actual apk is more likely to be compromised than source?

Comment: Yeah the string will be readable in the binary and also readable in a standalone file in the APK. If the key is in a standalone file, how do you manage the build process? Does the key have to exist on your build machine (and only on your build machine)?